# Lyx and the beamer class: Itemize breaks frame layout

Tags: beamer, lyx

I'm trying to create a presentation using the Beamer class in Lyx.

Following the example, I start a new frame environment, insert a title and add some text.

However, if I select some text to itemize, Lyx ends the frame environment and starts an itemize environment, instead of placing the itemize environment within the frame.

The online examples don't seem to have this problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please take a look at LyX's beamer manual in Help > Specific Manuals > Beamer Presentations. For your example, when you are in itemize, you just need to press "tab". See below:

[image]

Comment: Another quick question: How do I avoid breaking out of the nesting (and creating a new Frame environment) when pressing "Enter" in a frame?

Comment: I don't understand. If you break out then just press tab to go back in. Maybe you want "ctrl + return"? I don't think so though. If you write up an LyX example (this seems like a separate issue so separate question) and say "place your cursor here and press enter" or something like that maybe it will be more clear to me.

Comment: Placing the cursor after a frame title (or in a frame's nesting) creates a new line in the Frame environment instead of the "standard" environment. Also, pressing return in a nested environment breaks out of the nesting and sets the style to "Frame". Hitting Tab again gets you back in the nesting, but still with a Frame environment so that you've created a frame in a frame...

Comment: Work-around seems to be using Alt-return all the time.